# Not able to remove transitive dependency from gradle in an Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to remove the **transitive dependencies** from my Android project and for some reason `exclude` is not working when i try to remove a dependency from my particular dependency.

For example i want to remove `support-annotations` from my project

if i use

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
}
```

The dependency gets **excluded** and from the dependency tree. i can see the dependency tree by using ./gradlew app:dependencies [image]

But if i use

```
 compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
            }
```

Then i still see the dependency in the dependency tree.[image]

**So my question is that why is it not working when i try to remove the dependency from a particular dependency ?**

**Update 1:**

Also can anyone tell me what does the `star` (*) symbol next to dependency in the tree represent ?

**Update 2**

I am also using [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) I tried the same thing with Fresco and `exclude` **rule** seems to work for it

Dependency Tree of [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)
[image]

Dependency Tree when i exclude `imagepipeline-base` in Fresco

```
compile("com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0")
            {
                exclude group: 'com.facebook.fresco', module: 'imagepipeline-base'
            }
```

[image]

As you can see the `imagepipeline-base` dependency gets excluded. **So i don't know why this doesn't work for Android Support Annotations transitive dependency**

Comment: Is this only an example? Because you could just not explicitly compile the v4 library

Comment: @cricket_007 yes its just an example. I have a complex dependency tree but if this simple example can be solved then i will be able to solve the complex tree.

Comment: Which gradle version do you use? On 2.13 it works correctly.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking I am using     `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

Comment: Why that version? Does Android require it?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking Yes Its our CI server . That currently uses it

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking which version does it work on for you ? i tried using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2+' but the roblem still persists

Comment: I was using the plain Gradle, not the one provided by Google. In plain Gradle it works in 2.13.

Comment: you are showing dependencies for plugin internal configuration, prefixed with _, there must be "compile" one - does it contain excluded dependency?

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov Yup the _debugCompile also contains the excluded dependency. I think they are both identical

Comment: point is, in second case you exclude from "compile" configuration - you should look for exact "compile", not prefixed one - and see if there is your excluded dependency.

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov look at my update to question. it seems there is something weird happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So i have figured this out with the help of one of my friends. The reason why i was not able to remove `support-annotation` was because most of the other dependencies were using `support-v4` as transitive dependency and those `support-v4` also had their own copy of `support-annotation`.

Now there are 2 solutions to this

**Solution 1:**

exclude `support-annotation` from all the dependencies that contain`support-v4` as transitive dependency.

**Solution 2:**

exclude `support-annotation` only from my `support-v4` dependency and remove `support-v4` dependency from all other dependencies that have `support-v4` as transitive dependency.

**Note:** Using one of the above approaches i was able to solve my problem and figure out how we can remove transitive dependencies when they are referenced from multiple dependencies.

And regarding the **( * )** symbol it means that the dependency tree is for that dependency is already shown. Instead of showing the **whole tree** for those dependencies again gradle shows **( * )** symbol with them.

Sample `build.gradle` file is available [here](https://gist.github.com/krazykira/d3573e1877d938d55026ba87dca06372)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solution 2 worked for me. I was facing the same issues while working with a gradle project.

Answer (score 1):

There is more graceful solution: you can use **configueation.all** block in your **build.gradle** file like in example below:

```
configurations.all {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

It should exclude all transitive dependencies from all inner modules in your application.